# iptables forwarding through pptp

Tags: unix, android-source, iptables, forwarding, pptp

I am creating my own AOSP that contains my own apps and services. One of those services creates ppp0 interface and tries to link specific apps to be forwarded through that interface.
I have tried these commands but it was not working as expected.

> iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 10088 -j MARK
>   --set-mark 100
>
> ip route add via 10.0.0.201 dev ppp0 table 100
>
> ip rule add from all fwmark 100 table 100
>
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m owner --uid-owner 10088 -j SNAT
>   --to-source 10.0.0.201
>
> ip route add default dev wlan0

By the way, 10.0.0.201 is ppp0 interface Ip address.

This works fine with the user 10088, however when I use android chrome browser(which is NOT WITH UID 10088), I have a DNS problem, so any URL can not be resolved this means no internet except for my user with UID 10088.

I have analysed androids iptables after enabling vpn and I have found these lines:

```
-A st_mangle_OUTPUT -m mark --mark 0x3c -g st_mangle_ppp0_OUTPUT
-A st_mangle_OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 0-99999 -g st_mangle_ppp0_OUTPUT
-A st_mangle_ppp0_OUTPUT -j MARK --set-xmark 0x0/0xffffffff
-A st_mangle_ppp0_OUTPUT -j MARK --set-xmark 0x3c/0xffffffff
```

It sounds that they mark some packets and chose a range of uids, exactly what I want to do EXCEPT I wanna have specific uids not a range of them.

ip route provides me this:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  metric 310 
10.10.0.200 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.0.201 
67.219.95.113 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
70.83.139.168 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
72.38.129.202 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
104.167.113.112 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
130.102.128.23 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
139.112.153.37 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
159.203.8.72 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
190.181.129.115 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  scope link 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.110  metric 310 
192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  scope link 
209.81.9.7 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
218.75.4.130 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 
218.189.210.4 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0
```

I am looking for any solution that makes my job done, either solving this or another new solution.

looking forward to hear from you.

Thanks at advance.

Comment: Can you post the full output of `ip route` and `iptables-save`?

Comment: Hi @JoelC I have already edited my post, you can take a look on it now, thank you.

Comment: Please post the full output the two commands I posted earlier. This will give the full iptables settings (including nat, mangle) and the full IP routing table.

Comment: Hi @JoelC take alook now please, I can not run iptables-save on android unix

Comment: Is the issue with Chrome just related to DNS? Can you browse to a website by IP address?

Comment: Also, in your 4th line you have `--uid-owner` matching on `100` instead of `100881`. Can you try changing that?

Comment: Line 4 changed, and I can not go with ip

Comment: @JoelC I have edited them now